# Why is ScalaCheck discarding so many generated values in my specification?

Tags: specs2, scalacheck

I have written a ScalaCheck test case within Specs2. The test case gives up because too many tests were discarded. However, it doesn't tell me *why* they were discarded. How can I find out why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on the `org.scalacheck.Gen.fail` method and see what is calling it.

Incidentally, in my case the problem was twofold:

- I had set `maxDiscarded` to a value (1) that was too small, because I was being too optimistic - I didn't realise that ScalaCheck would start at a collection of size 0 by default even if I asked for a non-empty collection (I don't know why it does this).
- I was generating collections of size 1 and up, even though, as I later realised, they should have been of size 2 and up for what I was trying to test - which was causing *further* discards in later generators based on that generator.